# Using Firefox 50 in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automation, version

I am making a program with Selenium Python, which is an automation program.
The problem I have is that I must use Firefox version 50 and when I try to open the browser, it gives me an error and does not open the link.
I had a few questions, the first is that

Is there another package for automation in Python?

Is there a solution so that I can use Firefox version 50 in the program to work?

I want to open Firefox version 50 with Selenium Python

Comment: You'll probably need to use older versions of Selenium and/or Geckodriver.  There may also be some flags to set regarding marionette.  Include more details in your post including the exception and versions of Selenium and Geckodriver.

Comment: If I remember right it was marionette driver and a different protocol... but geckodriver did have some built-in legacy support for the protocol (via a flag?).  The bindings might be different though so you may need pre-3.14 Selenium version.  You may need a bit of trial and error to get things right.  Why the requirement for v50 of Firefox?